# Read .mif file in rom and export out data in verilog

Tags: io, verilog, ram, fpga

I am now doing a task that require me to input the data via .mif into the ram of Altera DE1 kit. The .mif file consist of 10 data and I wish to export out the data 1 by 1 according to the clock.
How do I able to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use ROM IP and specify your .mif.

[image]

Comment: The increment of the address in order to let the info been retrieve 1 by 1 is done at the top layer design? And how do I able to link it to the top layer design? Can show some steps?